# How to use vector (or different container) with non copyable class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, noncopyable, private-constructor

I have the following piece of code:

```
void f(){
  .....
  std::vector<PrepareLogFileThread> v;

  for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i){

    PrepareLogFileThread a(  
                list[i],
                LOG_TEMPLATE);
    a.start();
    v.push_back( a );
  }
  ....
}
```

class `PrepareLogFileThread` inherits from a `Thread` class that uses `pthread` (we use c++98 standard.... and I can use `auto_ptr`).

The problem here is that `Thread`'s copy constructor is private so that is doesn't mess up the execution or something (I am not the author of this class).

The idea here is that I create my `PrepareLogFileThread` objects, `push_back` to `v`, start them and then they all finish before `f` returns.

`PrepareLogFileThread` has in destructor call to `pthread_join` so that it finishes there.

But I can't because I copy `a` in line with `push_back`.

How can I do it without c++11 and changing `Thread`'s copy constructor?

I am using gcc 4.4.6 and I can use `auto_ptr`.

Comment: You'd need your own container, which doesn't require copyable types and allows in-place construction ("emplacement") like the C++11 containers. Or possibly add a level of indirection and store pointers to dynamic objects (carefully deleting them as appropriate, since you don't have any suitable smart pointers). [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/container.html) might help, if you really are stuck in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard containers assume their elements support value semantics (which includes, in your parlance, being "copyable" - among other things).

One option is to create a container of your own that does not require such semantics.   That is difficult, for various reasons.

Alternatively, have your container elements be something else which that does have value semantics, where the value uniquely identifies an instance of your  `PrepareLogFileThread` class.   An obvious choice for such a "something" is a pointer.  For example;

```
void f()
{
    std::vector<PrepareLogFileThread *> v;

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i){

    PrepareLogFileThread *a = new PrepareLogFileThread(  
                list[i],
                LOG_TEMPLATE);
    a->start();
    v.push_back( a );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind, however, that it is necessary to delete the elements of the vector `v` before it ceases to exist - objects created with operator `new` are not automatically destroyed up when done.   Failing to do this will result in a memory leak.

Note also that `std::auto_ptr` does not support value semantics, so should not be stored in a standard container.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the pointer to the object.

```
std::vector<PrepareLogFileThread*> v;
```

You should be careful about the lifetime of the object.